# Passing a string from one PHP script to the other without the link

Tags: php

I have a string which I evaluate in script1.php. I need to pass this string to script2.php. I so not want to embed the string into a URL and then pass. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: For getting data from **A** to **B** within your site you can use: GET, POST, SESSION, COOKIES, LOCALSTORAGE, CACHE or a DATABASE. Each one has its pros and cons. Read up on each of them, it will be really useful later on.

Comment: Will SESSION/GET/POST work, if the SESSION/GET/POST get set frequently in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different possibilities to solve this problem.
The first as you mentioned is **GET**. (e.g. as Link or even hidden via curl or AJAX. With curl PHP does the call. With AJAX the call is done on the server so that the user can see the string in the source code)

---

**POST**

The second way to do this is via POST.

Create a HTML form with script1.php and let it send the response to script2.php

```
<form method="post" action="script2.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="myString" value="myValue" />
   <input type="submit" style="/*you can stile me like a link*/" value="Click me" />
</form>
```

Now you can use this string in script2.php the following way

```
<?php
  $myString = null;
  if(isset($_POST['myString')) $myString = $_POST['myString'];
?>
```

---

**File**

If these two scripts are on the same Server you can use a file. In this case every request will see the string script1.php created.

```
<?php
  $myString = "myValue";
  file_put_contents("myString.txt", $myString);
?>
```

Now script2.php can read the content of the file and use it.

```
<?php
  $myString = file_get_contents("myString.txt");
?>
```

---

**Database / another application or backgroundworker**

Another possibility (very similar to the files) is the way of storing the string in a database. You can then read the value again and use it in script2.php.
If you can reach the database globally you can even distribute the string from one server to another like with GET or POST.

You can even start a local application (whith the exec function) that stores the information for you. script2.php can then can exec again to get the value of your new application

---

**Cookies**

For sure you can save the string in a Cookie. If the browser allows them you can read it with script2.php

script1.php

```
<?php
  $myString = "myValue";
  setcookie('MyString', $myString);
?>
```

script2.php

```
<?php
  $myString = null;
  if(isset($_COOKIE['MyString'])) $myString = $_COOKIE['MyString'];
?>
```

With this solution your data is stored at the client. The user has the possibility to see, change and manipulate the data if he wants to. On the other hand you can save storage on your Server.

---

**Local Storage**

Similar to cookies you can use JavaScript code to store the data in the local storage. The local storage is only on the client side. If you want to get the data on script2.php you have to call it via AJAX. Now you can process the data.

script1.php

```
<?php $myString = "myValue"; /*Be careful. your string must not contain ' otherwise you have to escape it!*/ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  localStorage.setItem('myString', '<?php echo $myString; ?>');
</script>
```

script2.php

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET['myString'])){
?>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhReq.open("GET", "script2.php?myString="+localStorage.getItem("myString"), false); //Be careful! You have to urlescape the value if necessary
  xhReq.send(null);
  var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
  document.getElementById("content").innerHtml = serverResponse; //Be careful. Escape HTML Tags if necessary here
</script>
<?php
  }
  else{
    $myString = $_GET['myString'];
  }
?>
```

---

**SESSION**

A usual way is a session. This combines a local storage on the machine (like a file) with the parameter methods (COOKIE, GET or POST)
The Information is stored on the Server with some ID. This ID is transferred from side to side with the parameter methods.

script1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $myString = 'myValue';
  $_SESSION['myString'] = $myString;
?>
```

script2.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $myString = null;
  if(isset($_SESSION['myString'])) $myString = $_SESSION['myString'];
?>
```

---

For sure there are a lot more if you use external programs.
You could use Websockets if they are available through an external library. or anything else.

**BUT:**
You can not use GET, POST, SESSION in an infinite loop. I'd recommend an external application or a file instead. Because PHP handles every request immediately in one script. If you give me more information about your "frequently loop" i could try to help you find a solution for that special problem.